# При установке pandas выходит ошибка Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\lapte\Parser\venv> pip install pandas

Collecting pandas

  Using cached pandas-2.1.1.tar.gz (4.3 MB)

  Installing build dependencies ... done

  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done

  Installing backend dependencies ... done

  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.

  │ exit code: 1

  ╰─> [12 lines of output]

      + meson setup C:\Users\lapte\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-huymt9rb

\pandas_9e2edb559ef34fc096e464c5cc64ba4e C:\Users\lapt      Project name: pandas

      Project version: 2.1.1

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 

Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\lapte\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-huymt9rb

\pandas_9e2edb559ef34fc096e464c5cc64ba4e\.mesonpy-zreogv0o\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.

╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

hint: See above for details.
```

Обновляла pip, подключала связанные библиотеки, пробовала в другом виртуальном окружении - ошибка повторяется

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3448]

Python 3.10.11

VScode version 1.82.2 (user setup)
```

Comment: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe

Answer (score 0):

Процесс установки pandas пытается найти vswhere.exe, который связан с Microsoft Visual Studio.

Попробуйте:

1. Установите Microsoft Visual Studio
2. Попробуйте установить pandas, используя предварительно скомпилированные бинарные файлы, чтобы избежать проблем с компиляцией:

```
    pip install pandas --only-binary :all:
```

3. Если у вас установлен Conda, вы можете попробовать установить pandas с его помощью:

```
    conda install pandas
```

4. Если ошибка сохраняется попробуйте:
5. Установить Visual Studio Build Tools
6. Перед установкой pandas, установить или обновить setuptools и wheel:

```
    pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
```

7. Попробовать установить pandas

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)